# Stop YTplayer video when link is clicked ... or just pause it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, ytplayer

Site plays a **full screen video with sound**.  The site was designed to play the video without sound.  When a link is clicked the other portions of the site appear on top of the video.

Unfortunately the client has insisted on having sound, so when something is clicked you still hear the music until the video ends.  I know it is possible to have the video stop or even have it muted when a link is clicked but I cannot seem to understand where exactly to implement this.  Your help is appreciated.  I'm not a jquery person so I'm rather dim on this.  Site uses the **YTPlayer** ( http://pupunzi.open-lab.com/mb-jquery-components/jquery-mb-ytplayer/ )

The site: http://www.bradfordweb.com/clients/concannon2/

The code in the page that is playing the video is:

```
<a id="P2" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'http://youtu.be/OgAr2jQr3rg',containment:'#home',autoPlay:true, mute:false, loop:false, opacity:.6}"></a>
```

The link is:

```
<div class="link-home"><div class="cl-effect-8"><a href="javascript:goTo('about'); "><span>ABOUT US</span></a>  </div></div>
```

I tried:

```
onclick="stop()"
```

and

```
stopYTP
```

I found the function in the jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js file:

```
stopYTP: function () {
        var YTPlayer = this.get(0);
        var controls = jQuery("#controlBar_" + YTPlayer.id);
        var playBtn = controls.find(".mb_YTVPPlaypause");
        playBtn.html(jQuery.mbYTPlayer.controls.play);
        YTPlayer.player.stopVideo();
    },
```

Help?

Comment: Does the video start automatically on page load, or does it require the user to start the video? Is the page's main content the video (ie users come to the page to see the video) or is it secondary content? If the video is secondary content and plays automatically with sound, the client is asking for a BAD user experience. Please try to talk them out of it.

Comment: Yes, the video starts on page load.

Take a peek at the link if you do not mind and you will see exactly what happens - it's a full browser background video.  And I have tried to talk them out of the sound - my vision was more of a subtle thing.  It is not an option at this point though.  ytplayer has that functionality, I just don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well and found it in the `onYouTubePlayerReady` function.

Look for it in that file and do the following changes:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  var player=$("#"+playerId);
  player.mb_setMovie();

  // Remove or comment out the lines below.
  // $(document).on("mousedown",function(e){
  //   if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a")
  //     player.pauseYTP();
  // });
}
```

That line just simply binds the mousedown event on an a tag and consequently pauses the player.

Hope that helps.